# Express NodeJS Routing Error text/html is not text/event-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple Node Express server setup that serves an html file with a bundle.js. Whenever I try to add a route that catches all routes and redirects to the homepage, I get an error in the console when I open an unmapped route saying

**"EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."**

I'm not exactly sure what this means, I was also having issues with trying to serve the index.html (Issues with the path for the file) so it's possible that might have something to do with this. I'm trying to serve the Index.html inside the build folder.

Project Structure:
[image]

Index.js (Server File)

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'public/build')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/build')});
    res.end();
});

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('triggered');
    res.redirect('/');
    res.end();
});


server.listen(3000);
```

Oddly enough, when I go to localhost:3000 It prints "triggered" in the node console and If I remove the "app.all" line of code that catches any other routes, then it doesn't throw this error anymore:

**"EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."**

However, If I remove the line of code that catches routes, I get the error "cannot GET /routename" as expected.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>project</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Content being rendered in the Index.html file

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/index.css';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <button onClick={null}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Index.js (Client side)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import store from './redux/store';

require('webpack-hot-middleware/client');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: can you describe index.html or maybe post the HTML content(after the react rendering)? Because for let's say an image which is not there in the `public/build` folder it will get a `text/html` rather than a image. Maybe you are opening a EventSource in the file

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I added the Index.html file, it's really weird because when I remove the "app.all" line, I don't get the error about EventSource, in terms of the actual content, there are no images, the content just includes a header (h4). On top of this, whenever I open the default page "/" route, the "app.all" function gets executed too and console logs "triggered"

Comment: Yes I know I wanted the html AFTER you render the `bundle.js`. and the problem is not because `app.all` it is because of the `res.redirect` I will answer it in a while, but wanted to know the actual content of index file, means what is happening after the bundle got rendered

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I have added the content being rendered in the post. Also just a question, why is the  app.all function event being triggered at all? Shouldn't the request be first intercepted by app.get('/') and just stop after that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Hey, I think I found the problem? In my client-side code for react, I was loading webpack hot module by doing require('webpack-hot-middleware/client') and after I removed it the error goes away.

Comment: Because in browser whenever you open a site it triggers a `favicon.ico` request. Which goes to the `app.all` section.

Comment: YEs! `webpack-hot-middleware/client` that's what I was asking, it takes a server side event from the backend server. :-)

Comment: You can share your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by getting rid the webpack hot middleware import statement in the index.js (client) file.

```
require('webpack-hot-middleware/client');
```

The Webpack middleware serves an EventStream and expects the EventSource's response to be served on text/event-stream and since the file is served over text/html, it throws that error.